# SVG: how to position text on top of svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to place the FAQ to be on top of this gray wave SVG. As in, the "Frequently Asked Questions" Would be on top of the SVG and the other text would be right below it still (like if there was a box around the FAQ question, I just want to shift it up). Is there a way to do that?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320"><path fill="#f6f6f8" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,128L40,117.3C80,107,160,85,240,96C320,107,400,149,480,186.7C560,224,640,256,720,261.3C800,267,880,245,960,229.3C1040,213,1120,203,1200,218.7C1280,235,1360,277,1400,298.7L1440,320L1440,0L1400,0C1360,0,1280,0,1200,0C1120,0,1040,0,960,0C880,0,800,0,720,0C640,0,560,0,480,0C400,0,320,0,240,0C160,0,80,0,40,0L0,0Z"></path></svg>
        <!--FAQ accordian-->
        <section>
          <div class="container faq">
            <h2 class="header-h2">Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <div class="faq-question">
                  <h5>How much does it cost?</h5>
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>                 
                </div>
                <div class="faq-question">
                  <h5>What will you do with Lorem?</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="faq-question">
                  <h5>What is the difference between the free and premium plans?</h5>
                  <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

Currently:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give the `svg` a class and position it absolutely on top with a z-index of -1, and then space your header-h2 accordingly.

```css
.hero {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.header-h2 {
  margin: 80px 0;
}
```

```html
<svg class="hero" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320"><path fill="#f6f6f8" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,128L40,117.3C80,107,160,85,240,96C320,107,400,149,480,186.7C560,224,640,256,720,261.3C800,267,880,245,960,229.3C1040,213,1120,203,1200,218.7C1280,235,1360,277,1400,298.7L1440,320L1440,0L1400,0C1360,0,1280,0,1200,0C1120,0,1040,0,960,0C880,0,800,0,720,0C640,0,560,0,480,0C400,0,320,0,240,0C160,0,80,0,40,0L0,0Z"></path></svg>
<!--FAQ accordian-->
<section>
  <div class="container faq">
    <h2 class="header-h2">Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="faq-question">
          <h5>How much does it cost?</h5>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>
        </div>
        <div class="faq-question">
          <h5>What will you do with Lorem?</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="faq-question">
          <h5>What is the difference between the free and premium plans?</h5>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either set a position for the  `svg` (absolute/fixed) and give it a `z-index:-1`, OR set a position for your `.faq` and give it a `top:1`

Comment: `z-index:-1` ;)

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 240px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.header-h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 3vw;
  padding: 1.5%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-top: 120px
}

.col {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 3%;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 1440 320"><path fill="#f6f6f8" fill-opacity="1"   d="M0,128L40,117.3C80,107,160,85,240,96C320,107,400,149,480,186.7C560,224,640,256,720,261.3C800,267,880,245,960,229.3C1040,213,1120,203,1200,218.7C1280,235,1360,277,1400,298.7L1440,320L1440,0L1400,0C1360,0,1280,0,1200,0C1120,0,1040,0,960,0C880,0,800,0,720,0C640,0,560,0,480,0C400,0,320,0,240,0C160,0,80,0,40,0L0,0Z"></path></svg>
<!--FAQ accordian-->
<section>
  <div class="container faq">
    <h2 class="header-h2">Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="faq-question">
          <h5>How much does it cost?</h5>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>
        </div>
        <div class="faq-question">
          <h5>What will you do with Lorem?</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="faq-question">
          <h5>What is the difference between the free and premium plans?</h5>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```